# Do "I have eaten that cake" and "I have eaten that cake up" have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I know that "to eat up smth" means to eat all of it. Now I have a question.

Do "I have eaten that cake" and "I have eaten that cake up" have the same meaning?

Do they both mean that the entire cake has been ingested?

Comment: As is often the case, including an *optional* preposition after the main verb *(to eat something **up**)* can impart some degree of "emphasis" (so *Eat it **up*** strongly implies *Eat it **all** up*, and/or *Eat it **with gusto / enthusiasm***). So *most likely* your second version would be intended to mean you ate ***all*** the cake, but it's not an absolute certainty. The first version might mean you recently ate the entirety OR a bit of some contextually relevant cake - or it might just mean you tasted a morsel of that particular *type* of cake many years ago.

Comment: (So you'll usually see that optional preposition included in metaphoric / emphatic [*You're so cute I could just eat you up!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22You%27re+so+cute+I+could+just+eat+you+up%21%22))

Comment: How about "ate that cake" vs "ate that cake up"? Do they both mean the entire cake was eaten?

Comment: Per my first comment, ***most likely*** it would mean you ate all the cake, but it's ***not an absolute certainty***. Including an optional preposition like this (***up***, here) often simply adds a little "emphasis", which you can "interpret" in the light of the context. In this case, it's perfectly reasonable to interpret "emphatic" as implying "all".